# See what options I used when I installed a brew package

Tags: homebrew

How can I check which options I installed a brew package with? For example, I have homebrew gcc installed. Is there someway to check if it was installed with the `--multi-lib` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`brew info` will display the options used. Also, each install contains a file `INSTALL_RECEIPT.json` in its Cellar directory for keeping track of used and unused options.